# How to protect MySQL database from sql-injection?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I am new to databases and security.

I am planning to put up a website.

I've read that sql-injection vulnerabilities can be very dangerous since the server might leak user passwords and credit-card information.

Are there any steps that I need to follow to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities?

I was going through a wiki on sql-injection, but I didn't understood the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '" + userName + "';
```

Answer (score 1):

you better use **prepared statement** from your programming source code, e.g. for PHP use PDO's prepare statement!

Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I used a private function that vetted all the parameters passed into my services (Models in today's parlance). In a large application you might as well make it a 'global' function that all your scripts/models access when you're accepting any parameters from your frontend

eg

```
private function protectMySQL($myParam)
{
    $myParam = stripslashes($myParam);
    $myParam = mysql_real_escape_string($myParam);
    return $myParam;
}
```

and then in each function

```
public function setMonthlyData($companyID, $userID, $resultArr)
{
    require_once("vo/Object.php");
    $myResponseObj = new Object();

    $myCompanyID = $this -> protectMySQL($companyID);  //vet $companyID
    $myUserID = $this -> protectMySQL($userID);        //vet $userID

    //.....etc
    //execute query using parameters
    //then return the result 
}
```